# how to call specific index from json in flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart, indexing

i have a json in which i am fetching data from to add to my code. what i want is to have access to data only from a specific index.

```
[
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce55270d648e9a5248a",
    "index":0,
    "guid":"58e73438-27fa-48bf-8127-ff4e42beaac5",
    "isActive":true,
    "price":"$252.77",
    "name":"James Lewis Blue Ledis",
    "type":"dress",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1539008835657-9e8e9680c956?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80"
  },
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce573d4e1ce44e5a5a9",
    "index":1,
    "guid":"e1d93cfe-b15a-4969-97e0-3b6b9ae967d0",
    "isActive":false,
    "price":"$289.88",
    "name":"Blue FLower Shoe",
    "type":"apparel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1543163521-1bf539c55dd2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
  },
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce522bd392da7b43d2e",
    "index":2,
    "guid":"0ee56032-db50-44c3-9234-5e213b8fde22",
    "isActive":false,
    "price":"$452.81",
    "name":"Yellow Blight Bag",
    "type":"bag",
    "image":"https://images.pexels.com/photos/934673/pexels-photo-934673.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
    "recommended":true
  },
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce5fdf98a105a5c14cb",
    "index":3,
    "guid":"fee6217c-ee7f-4e3e-91cc-24dfd91d6cfc",
    "isActive":true,
    "price":"$244.91",
    "name":"Black meter dress",
    "type":"dress",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550639525-c97d455acf70?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=726&q=80"
  },
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce5036de010a96ab185",
    "index":4,
    "guid":"2d9e8b22-90c1-4979-b904-2cc164626e10",
    "isActive":false,
    "price":"$335.17",
    "name":"Dynamic Pink Lobre",
    "type":"bag",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566150905458-1bf1fc113f0d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1171&q=80"
  },
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce52e2a60eed71c79b6",
    "index":5,
    "guid":"32db02a5-a12d-4f3e-a601-787211734ab1",
    "isActive":false,
    "price":"$414.69",
    "name":"Gucci Flems Onyx",
    "type":"bag",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548036328-c9fa89d128fa?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1169&q=80"
  },
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce52f14c39bb8366650",
    "index":6,
    "recommended":true,
    "guid":"1a0c388c-2ac7-4a49-85ba-50b12bc08f28",
    "isActive":true,
    "price":"$293.63",
    "name":"705 California",
    "type":"apparel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618354691229-88d47f285158?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=715&q=80"
  },
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce56b57e56f54676302",
    "index":7,
    "guid":"956527b1-c9d8-4c18-a6ef-e4b1dcd76640",
    "isActive":false,
    "price":"$293.57",
    "name":"Mid-week flavors",
    "type":"apparel",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560769629-975ec94e6a86?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=764&q=80"
  },
  {
    "_id":"636e0ce56c0ed15b28297895",
    "index":8,
    "guid":"119db62a-eaba-493f-b73a-5dcba04b69c1",
    "isActive":false,
    "price":"$348.63",
    "name":"Hermes Coysx",
    "type":"bag",
    "image":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1594223274512-ad4803739b7c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=757&q=80"
  },
]
```

for instance, in the json above, i want to have access to only indexes that has 'type:bag'. by the way, i dont want to hard code it. i am putting it in a listview builder

Comment: you want index or items ?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your list call `dataList`, you can access to items which its type is `bag`, like :

```
var result = dataList.where((element) => element["type"] =="bag").toList();

print("result = $result");
```

now result have only contains items which their type is `bag`.

Comment: was it what you want ? @alex